# how to live stream a Web Page from server side to YouTube and Facebook and also have a WebRTC output for the stream?

Tags: webrtc, video-streaming, streaming, rtmp, rtp

We had a requirement for recording and streaming the Web pages from a server side can anybody please recommend me a solution for that ?
we want to live stream the page YouTube and Facebook and play the video with WebRTC as well.

Comment: I don't know of any free solution, but I have a commercial offering for this if you're interested.... It's called Wrender (rendering of web content to streams), and can output web pages as video streams to pretty much anywhere you want.  brad@audiopump.co

Answer (score 0):

To play a WebRTC stream and forward it to YouTube, you need to set up a media server. You can then use FFmpeg to forward the stream to YouTube.

In [this blog](https://blog.ossrs.io/how-to-live-streaming-on-youtube-via-rtmp-or-rtmps-using-a-web-browser-e05819ee2228), the primary workflow is demonstrated:

```bash
WebPage --WebRTC--> SRS -+--RTMP--> FFmpeg --> YouTube
                         +--WebRTC--> WebPage(Viewer)
                         +--HLS---> DVR
```

> Note: You can also use OBS to publish RTMP/SRT stream to SRS.

While the blog post mainly demonstrates how to publish to YouTube, it is also possible to directly play the stream via WebRTC. For an example, refer to [this wiki](https://ossrs.io/lts/en-us/docs/v6/doc/webrtc#rtc-to-rtc).

This open-source and free solution is available for use. If you prefer not to run FFmpeg manually, a WebUI is provided to assist you in the process. Check out [SRS Stack](https://ossrs.io/lts/en-us/docs/v6/doc/getting-started-stack) for more information.